# How to simplify $e^{6b}$

Tags: exponential-function

Am I "allowed" in math to simplify **$e^{6b}$** to **$(e^{2b})^3$**?
If not, is there any other way to simplify **$e^{6b}$** to **$e^{2b}$**?

Comment: Your way is correct.

Comment: Ok. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are allowed to. $e^{6b}=({e^{2b}})^3$. This is because $a^{bc}={(a^b)^c}$

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: ...for nonnegative $a$.

Comment: I have added a bracket to your answer. $e^{2b^3}$ is ambiguous, it could also mean $e^{(2b^3)}$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri okay thanks

Comment: $2b$ or not $2b$?